# Angular regex error

Tags: regex, angular, forms, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I'm creating a form in Angular that requires the rate field to take only numbers with 2 decimal places. My HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"  (keypress)="_keyPress($event)" (ngModelChange)="Valuechange($event,salesorder,'Rate')"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="customerCode" #customerCode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="salesorder._dto.rate" [style]="{'text-align':'right'}" />
```

On every keypress event I'm calling `_keyPress()` method as follows:

```
_keyPress(event: any) {
        const pattern = /[0-9\+\.\ ]/;
       let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
        if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
            // invalid character, prevent input
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

The above regex works fine but does not restrict the number to 2 decimal places. I tried with various regex but could not implement the restriction to 2 decimal places. The last regex I used to do the same is as follows:

```
 const pattern = /[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0,2})/;
```

I have no much idea about regex.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the decimal place to 2 digits, you could use `{2}`.

`{0,2}` means match zero, one or two times.
`[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})`

**Note**
This uses an unnecessary capturing group `(\.[0-9]{2})` which could be written as `\.[0-9]{2}`

You could also use anchors to match from the beginning `^` to the end `$`:

[`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/y3pQUI/1)

or

[`^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/y3pQUI/2)

```js
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})$/;
var inputs = [
  "22.65",
  "22.6",
  "22.656"
];
for (var i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(pattern.test(inputs[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following regex:

```
const pattern = /^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$/
```

Or you may use shorthand character class `\d` instead of `[0-9]` i.e:

```
const pattern = /^\d*\.\d{2}$/
```

**Description:**

- `[0-9]{2}$` or `\d{2}$` will make sure that there are exactly 2 numbers after decimal point.
- You may replace `*` with `+` if there must be at least one number before point.